# retry requests with time interval

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/best-practice-with-retries-with-requests)

With `session.mount` I can ask `requests` to do as many retries as I want. But it seems like I can't control the interval between each request.

For now I had to use codes like this

```
    for retry in range(1, 5):
        logging.warning('[fetch] try=%d, url=%s' % (retry, url))
        try:
            resp = requests.get(url, timeout = 3)
            data = resp.text    
        except Exception as e:
            logging.warning('[try=%d] fetch_list_html: %s' % (retry, e))
            pass

        if data is False:
            time.sleep(retry * 2 + 1)
        else:
            break
```

Is there any better solutions?

Comment: Try `if data == False:` or some other relational check. Verify that data is actually False, because that is the only time the delay is done.

Answer (score 2):

According to `urllib3.util.retry`'s source code, you can modify `backoff_factor` to control delay between retries:

```
:param float backoff_factor:
    A backoff factor to apply between attempts after the second try
    (most errors are resolved immediately by a second try without a
    delay). urllib3 will sleep for::
        {backoff factor} * (2 ^ ({number of total retries} - 1))
    seconds. If the backoff_factor is 0.1, then :func:`.sleep` will sleep
    for [0.0s, 0.2s, 0.4s, ...] between retries. It will never be longer
    than :attr:`Retry.BACKOFF_MAX`.
    By default, backoff is disabled (set to 0).
```

In your link, it was set to `0.3`, maybe it is too small for you. So you can set it to `1`. `urllib3` will sleep for `[0s, 2s, 4s, ...]`, but won't longer than `120`

Comment: Does `requests` module rely on urllib3?

Comment: actually it doesn't rely on it as there is a built-in `urllib3` inside `requests`.

Answer (score 0):

But Timeout is a special exception type as well: you can do it by looking at the exception type:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts

Basically:

```
for retry in range(1, 5):
    logging.warning('[fetch] try=%d, url=%s' % (retry, url))
    retry_because_of_timeout = False
    try:
        resp = requests.get(url, timeout = 3)
        data = resp.text    
    except Timeout as e:
        logging.warning('[try=%d] fetch_list_html: %s' % (retry, e))
        retry_because_of_timeout = True
    except Exception as e:
        logging.warning('[try=%d] fetch_list_html: %s' % (retry, e))
        pass

    if retry_because_of_timeout:
        time.sleep(retry * 2 + 1)
    else:
        break
```

I would actually refactor this completly though to be exception led into a subfunction and use the Exception to break it rather then the break on the if...

[Edit - Thanks to Adam for spotting typo in code]

Comment: The last conditional is missing a colon after `retry_because_of_timeout`